# Getting vim to show the lines relative to other screen in splitscreen?

Tags: vim, neovim, line-numbers, split-screen

I am splitting one document vertically in vim using `:vsp`.

Each side displays the `relativenumber` relative to the last cursor position at that side.

I want to move a line from the left side to the right side using the relative number of lines.
Say: `:m-33`.

How could I get the `relativenumber` on the right side to count relative to the cursor position on the left side?

P.S.

(I'm using `NeoVim`)

I could not find any such option in the `:help`

Also, `vim` would need to know that both sides are the same file, so it is reasonable that it has no such feature.

Answer (score 0):

Cursor position is local to the window so there is always only one current line, which means that there is no native way to do *exactly* what you want.

But nothing is stopping you from dropping a mark on the left side:

```
ma
```

then switching to the right side:

```
<C-w>w
```

then moving the current line to below that mark:

```
:m'a
```